# React Reducer- take value from state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i have a reducer , in that i had give initial state

```
const initialState = {
  fullData: {},
}
```

And in page load am calling mainListData api and dispatching one action , then fullData got enriched with data.

```
  export const getDataActionDispactcher = () => dispatch => {
      performGet(GET_DATA_ENDPOINT)
        .then(response => {
          const payload = response.data;
          dispatch({
            type: GET_MAIN_DATA,
            payload: {
              ...payload,
              data: payload.results,
            },
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {

        });
    };

const myUploadReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MAIN_DATA: {
      return {
        ...state,

        fullData: action.payload,

      };
    }
```

this much is working and am getting fullData in my component

Again i do have some function returned in my reducer where i need this fullData. how  can i access this Data. 
For the new function i have some ID and i need to compare this ID from the fullData list and have to do some iteration. but am not sure how to get fullData in my new function written inside reducer.

```
export const getInfoActionDispactcher = (data) => dispatch => {
  const promises = data.map(asset => {
    return performGet(`${FILE_ENDPOINT}${data.id}`);
  });
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      **console.log(store.getState().fullData);
      const allAssets = store.getState().fullData;
      // not getting fullData here**
      });
      dispatch({
          //need to do
        },
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
    });
};
```

Comment: You can just pass the data as an argument from where you're calling the new function.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch some specific data by id *from* your store? Wait, you have some other function in the reducer you're trying to call? What and where is this *other* function being called?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. initially on page load am calling one api , and getting response and dispatching GET_MAIN_DATA, so fullData got data.Again i have some other function written inside reducer , where i need to have the fullData, how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Please update question with the function you're trying to call. If it's *in* the scope of the reducer, or in the scope of the file, you should be able to invoke it *in* the reducer.

Comment: @DrewReese i had updated question. its in the scope of reducer am asking , i need to get the fullData available for some other function written insider reducer

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk @midhunk?

Comment: @Vishnu: No, am not using it

Comment: So is the flow; invoke `getDataActionDispactcher()` action, `myUploadReducer` saves `fullData` in state, and now you want to invoke `getInfoActionDispactcher(fullDataFromState)` action *somewhere*? From what I can tell if this is correct, you should invoke the action from the component receiving the updated `fullData` state in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function or `useEffect` hook. If this is the correct flow can you also update and share the component code now that we see you're not trying to call some function from *within* the reducers, but rather dispatch another action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useSelector` :

```
// to get all users
useSelector(state => state.fullData)
```

---

Another way to access it :

```
store.getState(); // provide all the states

// you can also use it this way to just access `fullData`
store.getState().fullData;
```

Comment: am getting the same in component using useSelector. my question is how to get the same in reducer's another function

Comment: `store.getState()` will provide all the state , use this to get access only fullData :`store.getState().fullData` @midhunk

Comment: its not working. i had made my question more clean. Can you please check

Comment: i tried the same way , but am not getting. I think you are talking about how to get the data in component. i need the fullData to be available for another function written inside the same reducer. means fullData should be available for another function in same reducer